# Nikon D3100 converted to Infrared only takes red pictures

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, infrared, infrared-conversion

Mr father bought a Nikon D3100 that had been converted to take Infrared pictures, however the pictures just look like they have been taken with a normal camera and had the blues and greens filtered out leaving just the red (much the same as if they had been taken in a room with a red light).

Is this normal, and if so how do I edit the pictures so they look better? Or if this is not normal, how do I rectify the issue?

Comment: There are a few ways to convert a camera to IR. If you wanted a normal camera, you should return it if possible. If you wanted an IR camera, then find out exactly what was done to it. Various methods can be studied up on here: https://www.lifepixel.com/introduction

Comment: Note: If you're looking for otherworldly, dramatic infrared images, then it's not enough just to enable the camera to see infrared light. You also want to _disable_ it from seeing regular, visible light. Do this by using an _[infrared accessory filter](https://www.adorama.com/hy52rm72.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk_zH-Zmz5wIVCYizCh2Wgg8wEAQYBCABEgKVv_D_BwE)_ on the front of the lens.

Comment: @SolomonSlow pending the conversion that was done, that may not be necessary. Some conversions place a filter directly onto the sensor stack so that you can still compose through the lens. Knowing exactly what filters were removed/added to the stack is something OP should really look into...

Comment: What you describe may or may not be normal for an IR converted camera. An image showing what you're describing would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If the camera was modified to pass mostly IR light, then this is normal. You need to convert the images to monochrome.

Take a picture of foliage outside. Then desaturate completely. If the foliage is very white giving the image a surreal look, then the filter is working properly.

There are also IR camera modifications that leave more visible light, if you still have the specifications for the modification, please post them.

Comment: Sounds like only the IR filter was removed and not the CFAs. Definitely produce red pictures since sensors tend to respond strongly to near IR and there's lots of that. Suggest use of a visible light cut/IR pass filter on the lens for best IR photos.

Answer (score 1):

A normal color balance will produce red/pink images. Perfectly fine.

Easiest fix? Get a white sheet of paper outside, hold it up, take a photo. Then use that as the 'custom white balance' (I don't know your camera or how to do it).

Now your world will be in B&W... and you'll love it. More custom white balances can be done later with more neutral targets... but that'll get you going ASAP.